# Custom hook rerender problem when it return object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some custom hook which return object

```
export const useValue = (paramValue = undefined, options = undefined) =>
{
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  const _setValue = (value, options = undefined) =>
  {
    setValue(value);
    ...
  };
  
  return {
    getValue: () => value,
    setValue: (value, options = undefined) => _setValue(value, options)
  }
};
```

Then I use this hook in component A as prop to any component B. Because my hook return object it will be recreated as any other states will be changed in component A. So component B will be rerendered even when state in my hook is not changed.

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using useMemo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the object with `useMemo()` and an empty dependencies array, so it won't be recreated on each render.

However, your functions depend on some values, and we need to pass them to functions inside the memoized objec. We can use a ref to avoid declaring them as dependencies, and causing the memoized item to be recreated whenever `value` changes, or `options` is a non-memoized object.

Note the [caveats](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo#caveats) of `useMemo` - this is a performance optimization, and the cached value might released if React deems it necessary. So there might be some re-renders if the cache is cleared.

```
export const useValue = (paramValue = undefined, options = undefined) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const ref = useRef({ value, options, paramValue });
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = { value, options, paramValue };
  });

  return useMemo({
    getValue: () => ref.current.value,
    setValue: (val, opts = ref.current.options) => {
      setValue(val);
      ...
    }
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ori Drori. To solve my problem I just used useMemo this deps array [value] without using ref